# How should I handle an error in Python 2.7 in the initialization method for a C extension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 (which we need to support), the initialization function for a C/C++ extension should be declared with the PyMODINIT_FUNC macro, which effectively makes the function void. However, I'm not sure how we should handle errors that occurs during this function. We could throw a C++ exception within the function, but I'm not thrilled about that idea. Is there a better way?

Here's the background: In order to work around an architectural problem that we cannot address in a single release, we need to have the user call Python via a script that we provide rather than directly from the Python executable. By checking the process name, we can detect the situation where the user calls via the executable rather than the script. In this case, we would like to issue an error message and then terminate gracefully.

Comment: What's wrong with using one of the [PyErr_Set*](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_SetString) methods?

Comment: I was under the impression that nothing would check an error set with one of those methods unless the function in which it was set returned NULL. But perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: Exceptions are always checked after calling `init_module_name()`. (It's not explicitly stated in the documentation, but if you look at the examples, or if you read the source, you'll see that it is true.)

Comment: It looks like you're right. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [PyErr_Set*](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_SetString) methods.

Exceptions are always checked after calling `init_module_name()`.

It's not explicitly stated in the documentation, but if you look at the examples, or if you [read the source](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Python/importdl.c), you'll see that it is true.